# Автозамена символов ударения в vim

Tags: текст, vim

Возник следующий вопрос, в причастном моменте ежеминутно редактирую тексты из wiki в vim, при вставке коих частично некие слова, увы, с ударениями. "/" Поиск по коим не осуществим. К примеру Целиба́т, конце́рн.
   Возможно ли решение данной концептуальной проблематики, посредством автозамены проблемных символов, или же присущи некие более уподобимые решения, благодарю.

Comment: Приложите к вопросу пример таких слов :)

Comment: В Notepad++ удалось выделить и скопировать символ ударения `́`, а после удалить через диалог поиска/замены

Comment: Возможно ли это предопределить, эм, через vimrc

Comment: Думаю, через vim можно все-что угодно сделать, даже кофе заварить, но как это сделать я не знаю :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если в вашей системе доступна программа *sed*, можно «пропустить» текущий буфер через неё.

удалить все символы ударения:

```
:%!sed s/\\xcc\\x81//g
```

или заменить на что-нибудь:

```
:%!sed s/\\xcc\\x81/что-нибудь/g
```

здесь подразумевается, что ударения в вашем документе представлены последовательностью двух байт с шестнадцатиричными кодами `cc` и `81` (как в примере из вопроса).

---

а в самой программе *vim* возможность замены символов, представленных шестнадцатиричными кодами пока, увы, не реализована. см. `:help todo`:

> Substitute with hex/unicode number "\%xff" and "\%uabcd". Just like
>       "\%uabcd" in search pattern.

---

альтернативный вариант: [переключиться в режим «hex editor»](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2232/2338) и искать/заменять шестнадцатиричные цифры непосредственно.

---

другой альтернативный вариант (даже несколько): [игнорировать ударения при поиске](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7386/2338)

в частности, поиск `конц[[=е=]]рн` находит в том числе и строку `конце́рн`.